# How to connect OBS virtual webcam to Vmware

Tags: virtual-machine, webcam, device-driver

I installed **OBS** virtual camera as well. I can use it in browser as camera to share my screen.
but I need to use this in **Vmware** browser.
I meant share my own pc screen as webcam in **Vmware** browser.

Comment: Hmm, sadly I could not find a way.